# Google Maps V3: Markers only on streets?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

User should be able to place markers on a google map but only on streets. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Google is your friend:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/snap.htm

The basics of the solution is to ask for directions from the marker to itself.  Google will return directions via streets, which will happen to be a single point on the nearest street.

Update the marker location accordingly.

Comment: Thats excactly what I'am looking for. Thank you :-)